# Locked Print Settings Preservation When Updating Driver

Tags: printing, network-printer, print-server, preferences

I have a set of Ricoh printers on a print server. When I want to deploy a new version of the driver, it erases the printing preferences of all users mapped to the queue share. Example, if someone uses locked printing and sets a pin with username as Windows Login Name, then after I update the driver and that update propagates down to the users from the print server, their print preferences are reset back to the default of Normal print with no pin and they have to setup their preferences all over again.

We use normal print by default and let users set locked printing if they want. Not everyone does.

Is there a way to preserve user printing preferences when updating print drivers on the print server? Or is this just not possible?

Comment: Hi, when you update does the printer driver keep the same driver name ? I ask as some universal driver keep a standard name and allow one with the version.

Comment: It does. Just with the new version number. In this case, it’s the Ricoh UniversalPrint PCL6 driver.